# Colorcoding based on ComboBox item

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, tablelayoutpanel, color-codes

I'm using c# and Visual Studio 2010. I have a tablelayoutpanel with 8 rows and 8 columns. In one column the user will pick an item from a dropdown list in a combobox. Based on their choice, the row should assume a certain color. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to your Combo Box.

```
public void MyComboBox_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//change the color here
}
```

Make sure you add the event handler to the ComboBox properties.